# custom phone number regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using regex `^(\+91|[0]?)\d{10}$` for phone number validation. I want below output.

```
+911234567891 - valid
01234567891 - valid
1234567891 - valid
0123456789 - should be invalid as I want 10 digits after 0.
```

Please suggest changes in regex pattern
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a language tag too bc regexes have different flavors in different languages.

Comment: Something like [`^(?:(?:\+91|0)\d{10}|[1-9]\d{9})$`](https://regex101.com/r/sxowND/1)?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation?rq=1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Thanks a ton ! It worked. Please post it as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `^(\+91|[0]?)\d{10}$` pattern matches `+91` or an optional `0` and then any 10 digits. That means any 10 digit string will pass the test. You need to make sure 10 digits are allowed after `+91` or `0`, or make sure the first digit is `1` to `9` and the rest is just 9 digits.

You may use

```
^(?:(?:\+91|0)\d{10}|[1-9]\d{9})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sxowND/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?:\+91|0)\d{10}|[1-9]\d{9})` - 2 alternatives:

  - `(?:\+91|0)\d{10}` - `+91` or `0` and then any 10 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `[1-9]\d{9}` - a digit from `1` to `9` and then any 9 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Say for instance, in php - and javascript flavor you can use a [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/XMaCA0/1). Code below:

```
^(\+91|0?+)\d{10}$
```

The change is replacing `[0]?` with `0?+`. I removed the `[...]` for the sake of convenience. Then, the `?+` matches one `0` and won't let it go.

Another alternative is to list all the opportunities:

```
^(\+91\d{10}|0\d{10}|[1-9]\d{9})$
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/XMaCA0/2).

Comment: Thanks for the reply you guys are awesome, will surely try this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

Only mistake in your regex is a misplaced question mark.

```
^(\+91|0)?\d{10}$
```

You can remove the square bracket around '0' as it is a single character.

Comment: So as per above answer what case can fail?

Comment: 0123456789  will fail. Other 3 in your question will pass

Comment: But I want this to fail

Answer (score 0):

```
/^([+]{0,1})([0]|[9][1]){0,1}([\d]{10})$/
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.